# POSIX mq_receive does not receive correct value

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, message-queue

I am programming sending and receiving points between processes.

I declared some structures like this,

```
typedef struct Point
{  
    int x[100];
    int y[100];
    int count;
}Point;
```

and then I declared array of message queue and Point struct

```
mqd_t mq[10];
Point p[10];
```

and then I fork to make 10 child processes

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    pid[i] = fork();
    if(pid[i] == 0)
        break;
}
```

I inserted x,y with `Point` struct (and `p.count++;`) in each child process; I want to send it to another child processes, but it does not work.

I tried like this (just showing you simply, my code is more complex)

```
Point received_msg[10];
mq_send(mq[i], (char *)&p, MSG_SIZE, 0)
mq_receive(mq[i], (char *)&received_msg, MSG_SIZE, NULL)
```

and I checked how many times it sends to each message queue, and how many times the messages are received. 
I also checked those are the same counts.

But after receiving the message in another child process, I check the value of count in struct and it is just 0.

How can I receive the message to another process properly? Is it the mistake of data type when I receive?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but it is more urgent to read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you've provided isn't adequate.  You've not shown how you create the message queues.  You've not shown any error checking.  It isn't clear why a single process is both writing to and reading from the same message queue.  I've a suspicion that you've forgotten that once the processes fork, they each have their own memory and what one process writes into its arrays is not visible to any other process.

Comment: Also how is defined `mqd_t`?

Comment: What's the definition of `MSG_SIZE`?